# How to add extension .html in url asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the url:
`http://localhost:1714/Message/Index`

I want to show:
`http://localhost:1714/Message/Index.html`

How can I do it?

Comment: you can do this by writing url rewrite method in .htaccess file http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The whole idea of MVC route-mapping is to hide the implementation behind neat URLs.

Comment: I just wanto to custom the url. i was tired of looking at the URL that does not have the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify Web.config to map requests for your HTML files to TransferRequestHandler.

like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
      <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
```

This is explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works) by Jon Galloway.

And put this to your RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            ...
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}.html", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            ...
        }
```

Than accessing http://localhost:{port}/Home/Index.html will send you to your Home page.